# How to fix a non-working JavaScript login function?

Tags: javascript, html

My function does not seem to be working. Below this is the username and password boxes. What's supposed to happen is if you get the password or username incorrect, an alert pops up and you do not enter. If you do get it right, it brings you to the website.

That doesn't happen. What happens is when clicking on the enter button, it brings you straight to the href. How can I fix this only using JavaScript and not jQuery?

Here are the username and password boxes.

```
 <div style="text-align:left"> <strong>Username</strong> </div>

  <input id="usernameBox" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username here" style="margin-right:109px;" /> 
   <br/><br/>

   <div style="text-align:left"> <strong>Password</strong></div>

  <input id="passwordBox" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" style="margin-right:109px" /> <br/><br/>

  <div class="left">
   <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle;">
    <a href="https://myWebsite.org" onclick="return checkUP();">
     <span>Log In</span>
    </a>
   </button>
  </div>
```

Here is the function that is connected to the username and password boxes.I have nested an if inside of an if. I have attempted using "&&" and it still hasn't worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkUP() {

 var username = document.getElementById("usernameBox");
 var usernameText = username.value;
 var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox");
 var passwordText = password.value;

 if(usernameText == "Idk") {
  if(passwordText == "jhdsfij") {
   alert("Have names ready");
   return true;
  }
 }

       else if(usernameText == "Nick Crompton") {
        else if(passwordText == "retard") {
         alert("Fat bastard");
         return true;
        } 
       }

 else {
         document.getElementsByTagName("input").style.borderColor = "red";
         alert("Incorrect username or password");
         return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

Honestly, I am not entirely sure is to what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. I also have changed something in your code.

```js
function checkUP() {

   const username = document.getElementById("usernameBox").value;
   const password = document.getElementById("passwordBox").value;
   
   let result = false;
   
   const users = [ { name: 'Idk', password: 'jhdsfij', alert: 'Have names ready' },
                   { name: 'Nick Crompton', password: 'retard', alert: 'Fat bastard' }];
   
   const user = users.find(item => item.name === username && item.password === password );
   
   if (user) {
      alert(user.alert);
      result = true;
   } else {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"), input => input.style.borderColor = "red");
      alert("Incorrect username or password");
   }
     
   return result;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:left"> <strong>Username</strong> </div>

<input id="usernameBox" type="text" placeholder="Enter your username here" style="margin-right:109px;" /> 
<br/><br/>

<div style="text-align:left"> <strong>Password</strong></div>

<input id="passwordBox" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" style="margin-right:109px" /> 
<br/><br/>

<div class="left">
   <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle;">
     <a href="https://google.com" onclick="return checkUP();">
       <span>Log In</span>
     </a>
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks man! I've spent ages trying to fix it! Appreciate it! :D

Comment: "I have changed something in your code" What did you change? Good answers that provide working versions of an OP's code should at least mention what was changed, if not also why.

Comment: Actually I have changed everything

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
alert("Incorrect username or password");
return false;
```

to

```
alert("Incorrect username or password");
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended that **DO NOT** make login validation in javascript or other client side programming languages

but if you still want the code you can use

```
function checkUP() {

 var username = document.getElementById("usernameBox");
 var usernameText = username.value;
 var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox");
 var passwordText = password.value;

 if(usernameText == 'test' && passwordText == '123') {
        window.location.replace('http://yoursite.com');
 } else {
        alert('Error');
}
```